# Suffix Array Implementation in Java

Tags: java, string, refactoring, suffix-array

I'm looking to write an efficient n-order Markov chain method to generate random text strings given a set of example text.  I currently have a Java implementation that uses several layers of Maps, but it's clunky.  A suffix array would be perfect for my needs, but I'm not clear if that can be efficiently implemented  in Java.

In C I might do something like:

```
char exampleText[MAX];
char *suffixArray[MAX];
...
while(n<MAX && suffixArray[n++] = &exampleText[n]);
sort(suffixArray);
```

This gets gnarly in Java since I'd have to take substrings of `exampleText`, or turn `suffixArray` into an array of indices, or something else.

Any suggestions for a good approach to this in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String` will [typically] do that for you. (Typical implementations share backing arrays when created with `substring`, although that is subject to change at any time.)

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't even thought to try it out.  I just assumed it would explode.

Comment: Not anymore. Since Java 7 they do perform copy, so it is preferrable to write your own wrapper

Answer (score 2):

For anyone interested in more efficient ways of constructing the suffix array in Java, I once used a library called [*jsuffixarrays*](http://labs.carrotsearch.com/jsuffixarrays.html). The code is [here](https://github.com/carrotsearch/jsuffixarrays). It offers a range of construction algorithms to choose from and I found it to work very well. E.g. to use the SKEW algorithm you do this:

```
import org.jsuffixarrays.Algorithm;
import org.jsuffixarrays.ISuffixArrayBuilder;
import org.jsuffixarrays.SuffixArrays;
import org.jsuffixarrays.SuffixData;

String              exampleText = "....";
ISuffixArrayBuilder suxBuilder  = Algorithm.SKEW.getDecoratedInstance();
SuffixData          sux         = SuffixArrays.createWithLCP(text,sux_builder);

/* Then, to access the suffix array: */
sux.getSuffixArray();
/* And, to access the LCP array: */
sux.getLCP();
```

You can build without the LCP array if don't need that.

Answer (score 1):

You can make some variants form array of suffixes:

**First:**

```
public static String[] suffixes(String s)
{
int N = s.length();
String[] suffixes = new String[N];
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
suffixes[i] = s.substring(i, N);
return suffixes;
}
```

**Second:**

```
public static String[] suffixes(String s)
{
int N = s.length();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
String[] suffixes = new String[N];
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
suffixes[i] = sb.substring(i, N);
return suffixes;
}
```